# How to fix Page Not found error in NextJs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, frontend

I have the following folder structure

```
src/
├── app/
│   ├── pages/
│   │   ├── authentication/
│   │   │   ├── SignUp/
│   │   │   │   └── page.tsx
│   │   │   └── SignIn/
│   │   │       └── page.tsx
│   │   ├── page.tsx
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   ├── SignUp/
│   │   │   └── page.tsx
│   │   └── SignIn/
│   │       └── page.tsx
│   
├── component/
│       ├── signup.tsx
│       └── signin.tsx
```

I imported signup component inside both the authentication signup page and signup folder's signup page. and did the same for the signin component. inside of signup component, I have a link to route to the signin page in case a user is already registered, and inside of signin component, I have a link to route to the signup component. and inside of the app's page, I imported the signin component so that at the initial render, the signin component would be rendered. after the initial render, if I click on the signup link with

```
<Link href="../pages/authentication/SignUp">
```

it works fine and I am redirected to the signup page (http://localhost:3000/pages/authentication/SignUp) and in the rendered signup page,if I click signin link with

```
<Link href="../pages/authentication/SignIn">
```

I get page not found error and the path in the browser is(http://localhost:3000/pages/pages/authentication/SignIn). but if I use the following  link on the signin component

```
<Link href="../SignUp">
```

and the following link on the signup component

```
<Link href="../SignUp">
```

I can reroute to signup and signin pages without any problem and without any error. So what is going on in the first case? I would appreciate a detailed explanation or links. Thank you in advance

Comment: I don’t think it is necessary to go back in the path, as far as I know, the Link component takes the pages folder as the base, so it should be enough to put /SignUp or /authentication/SignUp, you don’t have to add the dots to go back in the fileSystem.

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how this works in a bit more depth: [IBM Relative pathnames](https://www.ibm.com/docs/tr/aix/7.2?topic=directories-directory-path-names)

Essentially, when you add a pathname with `../` at the front of it, this takes you from your current path, up a directory, (or in this case route) and then back down.

I suspect that this is why `../signUp` works correctly. Because you are moving up one "route" from signIn and then down again to signUp

Trying to do `../pages/authentication/signIn` likely does not work because of this same functionality. You are trying to move up one from signIn, and then down into pages, which does not exist. I am not certain, but `/pages/authentication/signIn` may work here because it does not have the relative path modifier `..` and so it would navigate to `https://site-name.com[URL]`